# why create CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2 instance always failed in a machine

Tags: windows, winapi, interface, directx, directshow

It's a real strange issue, the machine information below is from DXDiag. There is no error reported, but create CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2 instance always failed in the machine. It's okay to create CLSID_FilterGraph. Before create CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, I have called CoInitialize and created CLSID_FilterGraph. Only this machine has the error, what dll related with this interface or any function needed to call before to make it work? Thanks in advance.

---

### System Information

Time of this report: 4/24/2010, 09:46:58
       Machine name: TURION
   Operating System: Windows XP Home Edition (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_qfe.100216-1510)
           Language: Japanese (Regional Setting: Japanese)
System Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
       System Model: MS-7145
               BIOS: Default System BIOS
          Processor: AMD Turion(tm) 64 Mobile Technology MT-30,  MMX,  3DNow, ~1.6GHz
             Memory: 768MB RAM
          Page File: 376MB used, 1401MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     DxDiag Version: 5.03.2600.5512 32bit Unicode

---

### DxDiag Notes

DirectX Files Tab: No problems found.
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
          Music Tab: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.
        Network Tab: No problems found.

Comment: Did you call CoInitialize() ?

Comment: @rep_movsd: He DOES say he did ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't call CoCreateInstance a CLSID_FilterGraph .. this is pointless.  CoCreateInstance CLSID_CreateCaptureGraph2 and post up the code you use in CoCreateInstance and any HRESULT value you get returned.

The following code "should" work:

```
ICaptureGraphBuilder2* pCapture = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**) &pCapture) ;
```

If it doesn't look up the HRESULT returned in hr and tell us what it is (or look it up yourself).

Other than invalid parameters the only thing that ought to be able to fail you here is that the class isn't registered.  If so then this is something fairly majorly amiss ... this ought not to be possible.

Comment: And what is the returned HRESULT?  I hate to repeat myself but I have brought up the return 3 times nw ...